# How to prevent a process from terminating on a KeyboardInterrupt?

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing

I've been messing around with a Django project.
What I want to achieve is the Django project starting up in another process while the parent process initiates a load of arbitary code I have written (the backend of my project). Obviously, the Django process and parent processes communicate. I'd like a dictionary to be read and written to by the processes.

I have the following code, based upon examples from [here](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import os
import time
from dj import manage

def django(d, l):
    print "starting django"

    d[1] = '1'
    d['2'] = 2
    d[0.25] = None
    l.reverse()
    manage.start()

def stop(d, l):

    print "stopping"
    print d
    print l

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    os.system('clear')
    print "starting backend..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "backend start complete."

    manager = Manager()

    d = manager.dict()
    l = manager.list(range(10))

    p = Process(target=django, args=(d, l))
    p.start()

    try:
        p.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "interrupt detected"

    stop(d, l)
```

When I hit CTRL+C to kill the Django process, I'm seeing the Django server shut down, and `stop()` being called. Then what I want to see is the dictionary, `d`, and list, `l`, being printed.

Output is:

```
starting backend...
backend start complete.
starting django
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3, using settings 'dj.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
^Cinterrupt detected
stopping
<DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x141ae10; '__str__()' failed>
<ListProxy object, typeid 'list' at 0x1425090; '__str__()' failed>
```

It can't find the dictionary or list after the CTRL+C event. Has the Manager process been terminated when the SIGINT is issued? If it is, is there anyway to stop it from terminating there and terminating with the main process?

I hope this makes sense.
Any help greatly receieved.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea generally. It will only work with the built-in development server, which is not suitable to run in production.

Comment: Was starting to think that. Will probably have to figure out another way to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, as far I see no possibility to simply ignore exception. When you rise one, you always go straight into a "except" block if there is one. What I'm proposing here is something what will restart your django application on each ^C, but note, that there should be added some back door for leaving.

In theory, you can wrap each line with a `try..except..` block and that would act like a restart of each line, what will not be as visible as restart of whole script. If anyone finds a really-working solution, I will be the first one to upvote him.

You can set all inside your `if (__name__ == '__main__'):` into o `main` function and leave something like this:

```
def main():
    #all the code...

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    while True:
        try:
            main()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

Comment: The parens with the if statement are useless. The code won't help either: You catch the interrupt, but then the program terminates "naturally".